# how to scrap with scrapy by using the 'role' tag?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

this is the code i want to scrap,
i'm interest in the name class and the info class text.
i didn't figure how to scrap by the 'role' tag .
any idea?

[image: this the code i want to scrap, i'm interest in the name class and the info class text.]

**main.py**

```
  import scrapy
from ..items import UniversityItem



class UniversityLecturersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'university_lecturers'
    allowed_domains = ['www.runi.ac.il']
    start_urls = ['https://www.runi.ac.il/en/about/management/']

    def parse(self,response):

        items=UniversityItem()
        lecturers=response.xpath('//div[@role="rowgroup"]/li/text()').extract()


        for lecturer in lecturers:

                name=lecturer.css('div.name::text').extract_first()
                job=lecturer.xpath('//div[@class="info"]/p/text()').extract_first()
       
                items['name']=name
                items['job']=job
                yield items
```

**my item.py :**

```
import scrapy


class UniversityItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    name = scrapy.Field()
    job = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues in your code:

1. you are trying to use xpath and css expressions on strings. Once you have called one of the methods `get`, `getall`, `extract` or `extract_first`  the return value is no longer a selector and can no longer be used in chaining xpath queries.
2. The 'rowgroup' roll is on a `<li>` element not a `<div>`.
3. You are not using relative xpath expressions in the job selector.
4. You will want to make a new item instance for each item instead of recycling the same one because items like dictionaries are mutable.

What you actually want to do is closer to this:

```py
for elem in response.xpath("//li[@role='rowgroupt']"):
    name = elem.xpath('./div[@class='name']/text()').get()
    job = elem.xpath('./div[@class='info']/p/text()').get()
    item = UniversityItem()
    item['name'] = name
    item['job'] = job
    yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go more in details with [xpaths](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) you will find that `@` sign is not only used to access the class, it is used to access any attribute of the tag.

You can loop over the list using

```
lecturers = response.xpath('//li[@role="rowgroup"]')
for lecturer in lecturers:
    name = lecturer.css('div.name::text').extract_first()            
    job = lecturer.css('div.info > p::text').extract_first()
    # your code
```